# Is there an implementation for Delphi:TClientDataSet in C++ for MVS?

Tags: c++, delphi, tclientdataset

I want to migrate from Embarcadero Delphi to Visual Studio, but without a [TClientDataset](http://docs.codegear.com/docs/radstudio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DBClient_TClientDataSet.html) class it is very difficult.
This class represents an in-memory dataset.

I can't find any class like [TClientDataset](http://docs.codegear.com/docs/radstudio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DBClient_TClientDataSet.html).

Can anyone help me find something like this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual studio has DataSet and DataTable classes which are very close to what a TClientDataSet is in Delphi.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The .NET couple System.Dataset and System.Datatable are very 
different beasts from the TClientDataset.

Filtering and binding are done on another class (Dataview), 
dotNET DataGrid hides this a little. Extract method is the
nearest a datatable provides in termes of filtering (it returns
an array of pointers to DataRows).

Grouping is not so powerful as in TClientDataset, as also indexing
is poorer. (As in dotNet 1.1)

There's no record cursor on DataTable, so the positioning is on 
the visual controls - it takes 10 lines of codes just to get the 
actual record out of a DataGrid.

So the easiness of positioning the cursor on grid and get the 
value of the field of the dataset does not exist.